# Parameterized queries causing ECONNABORTED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, axios

Trying to make a GET call from the front end to select the username in the row where user_id = 1 by using parameterized queries. Hard-coded queries work fine, but parameterized queries cause the request to be aborted and returns the following error in dev-tools console:

```
message: "Request aborted", name: "AxiosError", code: "ECONNABORTED", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
```

EDIT: I've edited my code to try and narrow down the issue.
EDIT 2: edited again, may have been out of sync

/server/index.js

```js
require("dotenv").config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" });
const express = require('express');
const pool = require(__dirname + "/config/db.config.js");   // *
 
const app = express();
 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
 
const getUsers =  (req, res, next) => {  
  let userID = Number(req.query.user_id);
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 1', (error, users) => {
    if (error) {
      next(error)
    }
    res.status(200).json(users.rows)
    console.log(userID)
  })
}
 
app.get('/users', getUsers)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});
 
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(
    `# Server started on port: ${PORT}`);
})
```

The issue is that when I try using parameterized queries, the requests fail. The hardcoded `user_id = 1` above works, and outputs the correct row. But the following fails:

```js
const getUsers =  (req, res, next) => {  
  let userID = Number(req.query.user_id);
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1', [userID], (error, users) => {
    if (error) {
      next(error)
    }
    res.status(200).json(users.rows)
    console.log(userID)
  })
}
```

When I `GET http://localhost:3001/users?user_id=1` with those changes, Postman just shows "Sending request..." endlessly. Whereas with the hardcoded `user_id = 1`, Postman returns the correct row and server console shows "1" at every GET request.

Comment: Oh lol. Is there a better way to refer to the stack?

Comment: What type is user_id in the DB?  Could it be that req.query.user_id is a string type?

Comment: Nope, that’s just what it’s called, with the caveat that I don’t get naming these stacks since any part is replaceable ‍♂️

Comment: @DanielBank data type of user_id is serial4. Is that why?

Comment: Try coercing it to a number: `const user_id = Number(req.query.user_id);`

Comment: What version of `pg` are you using? You can check the exact version by looking at the `node_modules/pg/package.json` file

Comment: `"version": "8.11.3",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `return`:

```
const getUsers =  (req, res, next) => {  
  let userID = Number(req.query.user_id);
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1', [userID], (error, users) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
//    ^^^^^^
    }
    res.status(200).json(users.rows)
    console.log(userID)
  })
}
```

Without this, when you get an error, it will try to call `next` first, then try to send `res.status(200)`, then fail with an exception when accessing `.rows` on `users`. This may crash the server or at least seems to make express abort the response that would be sent by the default error handler.

Your solution that converts the code to use promises (with `async`/`await`) is much better, as it avoids such pitfalls with error handling. Now just make sure to use *express.js v5* which does natively handle rejections of promises returned by middlewares.

Comment: Great catch and that missing return was probably my fault (OP [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77254921/3) had `throw error` and I said change it to `next(error)`)

Comment: @Phil Oh if they had `throw error`, then it just crashed the server with no chance for expressjs to send a response. Still, it should have been visible with a load error message in the logs…

Comment: This was it.. for want of a missing `return`.... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what could have been causing the issue, but I created a new `db.js` file in `/server` (as opposed to using `const pool = require(__dirname + "/config/db.config.js");` Within that file is the following:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
  user: '[USERNAME]',
  host: '[HOST_IP]',
  database: '[DB_NAME]',
  password: '[PASSWORD]',
  port: 5432, 
});

module.exports = pool;
```

I updated `/server/index.js` to:

```js
// /server/index.js
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('./db'); // Path to your db.js file

const app = express();

app.get('/users/:user_id', async (req, res) => {
  const userID = req.params.user_id;
  
  try {
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1';
    const result = await pool.query(query, [userID]);

    res.json(result.rows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error executing query:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Now, sending `GET http://localhost:3001/users/1` via Postman returns the row where `user_id = 1`

Comment: What was in your `db.config.js` before?